# Change Facebook Bar Colour (Solution)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm currently working on a Google Chrome Extension which changes the colour of the blue bar on Facebook upon loading the page.

Upon inspecting the code, there is an image which overlays the blue bar and so any background colour changes remain unseen.

Current code:

```
document.getElementById('pagelet_bluebar').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
document.getElementById("blueBarDOMInspector").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Currently, I've set the status to invisible, and the bar changes colour however only the bar remains.

How can I target the background image in the CSS to remove it/hide it?

**EDITED 16/02/2016 (SOLUTION):**

(MANIFEST)

```
 {
    "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "MonoChromeBook",
  "description": "This extension will make a better looking site",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "https://www.facebook.com/*"
   ],
 "content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
  "css" : ["hello.css"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}
  ]
}
```

CSS

```
.sidebarMode ._50tj {
background-color: black;
 }

._5rzs._5v6d ._5v6e {
visibility: hidden;

}
```

**EDITED 10/02/2016:**

Blue menu bar has been modified so further research is required in adjusting the bar colour again.

Background and other divs are still editable.

Comment: `style.backgroundImage`

Comment: Downvoted: please do not embed your own answer in the question, instead post it as another answer.

Comment: Please can I ask why?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions let you inject javascript & css therefore inject a css that override standard facebook css, do not parse document with JS. Is is the less elastic solution.

Add to the manifest:

```
 "content_scripts": 
 [ { 
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"], 
      "css": ["fix.css"], 
      "js": ["script.js"]
 } ],
```

Comment: If you could provide a manifest / CSS snippet here, would be a better answer. Right now it's more of a comment.

Comment: How can I achieve this?

Comment: Withdrawing my upvote, since it's not a useful example at this point.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("blueBarDOMInspector").style.backgroundImage = 'none';

Answer (score 0):

I change the `bluebar` color with `CustomStyleScript` extension just with this code:

```
._2s1x ._2s1y{background-color:#922722;}
```